# OpenMP Tasks : Searching multiple Keys in a list using Binary Search

Tags: c, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp, binary-search

I am trying to use the OpenMP task construct to search multiple keys in an array simultaneously. But my parallel code seems to be much slower than the serial code.
**Could you please suggest changes to make the parallel code faster?**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int binary_search(int array[],int key,int size){
  int low=0,high=size-1;
  while(low<=high){
    int mid = (low+high)/2;
    if(array[mid]==key){
      return 1;
    }else if(key<array[mid]){
      high = mid-1;
    }else{
      low = mid+1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}

void main(){
  int size=10000000;

  int *array = (int*)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

  // Initializes the array
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    array[i] = i;
  }

  // exists array stores if the ith key is in the Original array or not
  int *exists = (int*)calloc(size,sizeof(int));

  // SERIAL REGION
  double end,start = omp_get_wtime();
  for(int key=0;key<(size);key++){
      exists[key] = binary_search(array,key,size);
  }
  end = omp_get_wtime();

  printf("\nSerial execution time : %lf\n",end-start);


  // Reset the exists array to 0 values
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    exists[i]=0;
  }

  // PARALLEL REGION
  start = omp_get_wtime();
  #pragma omp parallel default(none) shared(array,size,exists)
  {
    #pragma omp single
    {
      for(int key=0;key<(size);key++){
        #pragma omp task shared(array,size,exists) firstprivate(key)
        {
          exists[key]=binary_search(array,key,size);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  end = omp_get_wtime();

  printf("\nParallel execution time : %lf\n",end-start);
}
```

This are the results:

Serial execution time : 1.383815 
Parallel execution time : 10.438401

**Compiler**: GCC 5.4.0

**Cores** : 8 core

 Thank you in advance..
Edited : Included the changes suggested by John Bollinger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem I see is the `#pragma omp critical`.  That will cause a large amount of unnecessary locking.  You don't need a critical region because no element of `exists` is accessed by more than one thread inside the parallel region.  It is fairly expensive to acquire and release locks, and you are doing a comparatively large amount of that, so it is plausible that that completely explains the performance issue.

Additionally, you shouldn't need the `#pragma omp taskwait` at the end of the parallel construct, for all explicit tasks bound to the parallel region are guaranteed to be completed before control passes out of the construct.  But I doubt that's causing any performance problems.

**Update**

I performed some experiments:

- the original code exhibited an even more pronounced performance difference for me than described in the question: ~0.39 s *vs* ~14.3 s.
- I switched from an `omp single` thread for generating tasks to an `omp for`, yielding a parallel performance increase of about an order of magnitude on my 12-virtual-core machine.  Individual runs varied widely in parallel performance, however, from 0.1 s to 1.8 s.
- Probably not surprising, I saw similar performance to the previous when I got rid of the outer `omp parallel` region and annotated the loop as an `omp parallel for`
- I got a substantial improvement from the parallel code (~0.09 s; occasionally < 0.05 s) from getting rid of the explicit tasking, and just relying on a parallel `for`.
- I shrank the problem size in the original code by factors of two, four, and
  eight, and observed the timing to scale about linearly.

That is telling me that at least in my implementation, explicit tasks carry a pretty large overhead.  I don't find that particularly surprising.  Recognize that in order to create an explicit task, the thread doing so must allocate and initialize an object memorializing the task's data and execution environments, and must enqueue that object on a shared task queue (synchronization required).  Then, the thread that executes such a task must dequeue the task data and set up the data and execution environment before it can perform the actual work of the task.

In this case, all of that seems to cost about one microsecond for a task whose body costs about 40 nanoseconds.  The take-home message would be to avoid fine-grained explicit tasks.

Comment: I tried the suggested changes and removed the #pragma omp critical but still the performance hasn't improved by much.

Comment: @Coder360, I think explicit tasks have a fairly high overhead, and you're creating and running 10,000,000 of them.  See my answer update for an empirical analysis (at least of the OpenMP implementation provided by my compiler).

Comment: I was feeling the same that explicit task creation might be the reason for slowdown. Thank you for explaining the issue in detail. As well as your suggestion of using "omp for" also showed phenomenal improvement. Thank you for your time and prompt reply.